# Eclipse coverage reports that branches missed but why?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, code-coverage

I want to coverage all of if branches. I create a dumb class with multiple if...else, and test it with all branches conditions to test coverage. The Eclipse reports abount 1 of 4 branches missed and 2 of 4 branches missed. But why it happens? Where are the missed branches?

The class with if...else conditions:

```
public class Coverage {

  public void function(Object o1, Object o2) {

    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {

      System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);

    } else if (o1 != null && o2 == null) {

      System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);

    } else if (o1 == null && o2 != null) {

      System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);

    } else if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {

      System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);

    }
  }
}
```

The test:

```
public class CoverageTest {

  Coverage c;

  @BeforeEach
  public void beforeEach() {
    c = new Coverage();
  }

  @Test
  public void testFunction_null_null() {
    c.function(null, null);
  }

  @Test
  public void testFunction_object_null() {
    c.function(new Object(), null);
  }

  @Test
  public void testFunction_null_object() {
    c.function(null, new Object());
  }

  @Test
  public void testFunction_object_object() {
    c.function(new Object(), new Object());
  }

}
```

The Eclipse coverage report:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure eclipse is not executing some earlier version of the tests when some of them were missing? If that's not it, seems like a bug in eclipse, the tests cover all branches. Ran it with intellij just to be sure and got 100% coverage.

Comment: Each _if_ statement has 2x2=4 branches because it contain of two conditions which are combined with `&&`. Some of the combinations can never be satisfied because they are caught in an previous if statement: `else if (o1 == null && o2 != null)` can be simplified to `else if (o1 == null)` (`o2` cannot here `null` because of the first _if_) and `else if (o1 != null && o2 != null)` can be simplified to `else`. Consider to use nested _if_ statements without `&&` instead.

Comment: @Chaosfire It's about branch(!) coverage. Do not trust any IDE, especially not IntelliJ.

Comment: @howlger Do you mean the conditions that are always true, in the last 2 `else-if`s? It's useless code, but those conditions can be satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missed branches are dead code.

Each of the *if* conditions consists of two Boolean conditions, resulting in four branches. But only in the first two *if* conditions all combinations of the Boolean conditions are covered by the test. The **last two *if* statements contain unnecessary conditions** that are already **handled in previous *if* statements**:

```
public void function(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
        System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
    } else if (o1 != null && o2 == null) {
        System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
    } else if (o1 == null) { // o2 != null (o2 == null is already caught in first if-statement)
        System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
    } else { // o1 != null and o2 != null (everything else is caught in previous if-statements)
        System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
    }
}
```

Or simplified even further:

```
public void function(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (o1 == null) {
        if (o2 == null) {
            System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
        } else {
            System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
        }
    } else {
        if (o2 == null) {
            System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
        } else {
            System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some clarification needed, for me at least. Those conditions are unnecessary, but can be satisfied, the corresponding code in the blocks gets executes. Are the conditions optimized (removed) by the compiler?

Comment: Yes, I also don’t understand why the "if" statement is not considered as a whole, but as separate "else if" branches.

Comment: @Chaosfire Yes, these conditions are unnecessary because they are always `true`, so the cases where these conditions are `false` are not covered. No, neither `javac` nor ecj removes them. Such an optimization would require checking whether there are side effects and all permutations would have to be checked, which is exponential in effort (which is probably why no compiler does this optimization). Use the _Bytecode_ view if you want to dig into the bytecode yourself.

Comment: @sdorof The bytecode will be executed, not the source code. And in the bytecode `if (<cond1> && <cond2>)` becomes two nested _if_ statements, in your case each `<param>==null`/`<param>!=null` condition becomes [`ifnonnull`/`ifnull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.ifnonnull).